# Windows Server 2003 UTF-8

Tags: windows, unicode

I have an application that works with data received from TCP/IP. Data encoded UTF-8.
It's okay if the data come in English. But errors occur when the data with Russian characters.
How to set up the windows environment to work the application with UTF-8 ?

Comment: I don’t see any connection to Windows at all. If the application can’t handle UTF-8 or whatever Unicode encoding you’d like, you’re simply SOL. Contact the manufacturer/developer of the application.

Comment: You should contact the author of the application to discover the reason your having these problems.  If the data was actually encoded as UTF-8 it would be working.